# What was the point of Locutus of Borg's red laser?

Tags: star-trek

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* Episode *The Best of Both Worlds* Captain Picard is abducted by the Borg and altered to serve as Locutus. As a part of this, they attach a red laser to one of his implants. **What is the point of this?** It is never mentioned in the show and, similarly, it never appears to have been used as a weapon by Picard.

**Does this laser serve a purpose?**

[image]

Comment: The Borg love power point presentations.

Comment: That aside, the Borg loved general purpose modular attachments unless a specific task called for a task specific tool to be attached to a drone

Answer (score 2):

Intimidation presumably, it also could be an actual part of the hardware like a rangefinder type device. I'm honestly going to go with Rule of Cool above all else though.

Comment: The Borg don't seem to have the emotional tact to do "intimidation" in universe.

Comment: @cde They may not intuitively understand that un-assimilated species have emotional reactions, but perhaps they could statistically analyze the outcomes of their efforts against various species, compare that to the equipment their members were equipped with in each situation, and conclude that humans are intimidated by visible lasers. :)

Comment: I mean The Borg don't use intimidation as a tactic.